# Weird lines in python file, can't extract column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, identity-column

```
  0 0: 1
  0 1: 1
  0 1: 0
  1 0: 0
```

I have a file, that looks like something above.

I am trying to extract this by columns into arrays by using `numpy.loadtxt` of python. Ideally, I want many arrays, or at least a data structure in which the arrays are `[0,0,0,1], [0,1,1,0]`. To my utter discomfort, because there is that semicolon after the second number, I'm unable to use `numpy.loadtxt`. Would anyone have any solutions to how to either surpass that, or simply remove that semicolon without having to really separate the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.loadtxt(file, converters = {1: lambda s: int(s.strip(":"))})
```

From [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

> **converters** : *dict, optional*
>   A dictionary mapping column number to a function that will convert that column to a float. E.g., if column 0 is a date string: converters = {0: datestr2num}. Converters can also be used to provide a default value for missing data (but see also genfromtxt): converters = {3: lambda s: float(s.strip() or 0)}. Default: None.

Comment: Hi thank you so much! Quicker question. My file actually has two lines above it that have only 1 column, so this is giving an error (because it says index out of line). Is there a way I can apply this to a dataframe in python skipping the first two lines or something?

Comment: If it's the first two lines of the file, looks at the `skiprows` parameter of `np.loadtxt`. If it's two lines in the middle of the file, sorry I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much, 
I'm running into a slight problem. I have another file formate that has 300 lines, same file format.
testdata = np.loadtxt(testfile, converters = {47: lambda s: int(s.strip(":"))}, skiprows = 2)
This is the code I use to put it into an array. However, the testdata only has 135 lines. 
Why is this?

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of what the data looks like in the other file? It'd be good to have a look at the first few lines and the 134-136th lines.